# CORS Error in Angular 4 map function through php

Tags: php, angular, angular2-services, angular4-httpclient

I am working on Angular4 Project.

For testing, first I had done the get request to any  json api and its worked well.

Now I am working to connect the php file and testing it. In test.php I had

```
echo "string";
```

Now in console I am getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/php-file/test/test.php.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I also attached screenshot of it. I had googled it but unable to get any solution for this.

[image]

then I had edited the test.php like below. Is it right way to do so?

```
<?php
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
      $data = ['news','dfdf','ddd'];
      echo  json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: I had edited the test.php like below image. Is it right way to do so?

Comment: Can you add your angular code where you are calling post. Including ehaders

Comment: This is the service method where I am calling php file :`getData()
  {
     return this.http.get("http://localhost/php-file/test/test.php").map(res => res.json());
   
  }` @DheerajKumar

Comment: you haven't included any headers?

Comment: I had included in test.php file. I mentioned this in above question. @DheerajKumar, Is this right way to do?

Comment: For get request, it should work this way. For post you need to include headers in angular

Comment: Help me for Post request. Please give a example. @DheerajKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to do. You need to include headers in angular as well.

```
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


 headers = new Headers();
      requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
      this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
      this.headers.append('Cotent-Type', 'application/json');
      this.requestOptions.headers = this.headers;

      return this.http.post("http://localhost/php-file/test/test.php",  this.requestOptions).map‌​(res => res.json());
```

This is how you should make post request. Make sure to subscribe this call and then you can get data from return.

I hope it helps.